# Ember computed property for retrieving one record out of a hasMany relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, has-many, computed-properties

Here's my situation, simplified:

```
// model/price-source.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('product')
)};

// model/product.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
  priceSources: DS.hasMany('price-source')
)};
```

In my products template, I want to be able to simply refer to the source with the lowest price, like so:

```
// templates/products.hbs

{{#each model as |product|}}
<span>{{product.cheapestSource.price}} €</span>
{{/each}}
```

How would I go about setting up the cheapestSource computed property? I imagine I'd have to do something like this:

```
// model/product.js

  cheapestSource: Ember.computed('priceSources', function() {
    let sources = this.get('priceSources');
    let cheapest = sources.get('firstObject');

    // iterate over sources and set cheapest to whichever has the lowest price

    return cheapest;
  })
```

The problem is, I have little idea how to loop through the hasMany relationship (apart from using the handlebars {{#each}} helper), and whether a computed property can even consist of a single Ember Data record from another model. Does sources.@each somehow play into this, if so, how?

Any help and ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by sorting the priceSources into a computed property sortedPrices, then calling the firstObject of the sortedPrices in the template. Will edit this post with the actual solution soon.

It took ages to test because I didn't realize that commenting out handlebars blocks will break the rendering of html inside them. Note to self...

---

EDIT: This did it:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  priceSources: DS.hasMany('price-source'),
  sortProperties: ['price:asc'],
  sortedSources: Ember.computed.sort('priceSources', 'sortProperties')
});
```

Then in the template:

```
<span>{{product.sortedSources.firstObject.price}} €</span>
```

Works ok, without a ton of code.

Answer (score 0):

This you can do on a controller where you need to use cheapestSource.

```
   cheapestSource: Ember.computed('priceSources', function() {
        let sources = this.get('priceSources');
        let cheapest = sources.get('firstObject');   
        let array = sources.mapBy("price");
        let min = array.reduce(function(a, b, i, array) {return Math.min(a,b)});
        sources.forEach(function(source){
          if (source.get("price") == min){
            cheapest = source;
          } 
       });
    return cheapest;
    })
```

Model is bit hard to achieve what you want this is one why using one computed and after template is render computed becomes object that you need.

```
cheapestSource: Ember.computed('priceSources', function() {
        let product = this;
        this.get('priceSources').then((sources)=>{
        let array = sources.mapBy("price");
        if(array.length>0){
        let min = array.reduce(function(a, b, i, array) {return Math.min(a,b)});
        sources.forEach(function(source){
          if (source.get("price") == min){
            product.set("cheapestSource", source);
          } 
       });
      }
    });
  })
```

When I have issues like this I use active model adapter on Rails and return  for example cheapestSourcePrice as part of product in my custom serializer  then in Ember product model just add cheapestSourcePrice and in template {{product.cheapestSourcePrice}} You don`t want ember to do heavy lifting like this but if you don`t control the server then do it like this. And one more thing after it sets source to cheapesetSource computed is no more until refresh. If you need it to stay computed you must add one more property on model then set him insted example

cheapestSource2: DS.attr()

this will allow for it to be an object

product.set("cheapestSource2", source);

and then in template
{{product.cheapestSource}}{{product.cheapestSource2.price}}

first property you call is there so computed is called.

Comment: I am reading this [relationships as promises](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises)  guide. can we access it directly like you are doing ?. if possible explain in your answer ..just for my learning. thank you .and also dependent key `priceSources.@each.price` may be useful. I will remove my comment once you read

Comment: I did this on a controller now I see why you ask this question he did it in a model thx for checking.

Comment: @Sedad.Kosovac Unfortunately no priceSource object is showing up (in Ember Inspector). I'm not getting errors. I tried `return this.get('priceSources').get('firstObject')`, also tried `return this.get('priceSources.firstObject')`, but no. 

Since I'm going to need the sources sorted anyway, a better way to get the cheapest one would probably be to sort first, then retrieve firstObject in the sortedSources computed property.

Comment: I edited my answer for model what will work I presume you will not sort it in computed property on model.

Comment: @Sedad.Kosovac Thanks, I will try your solution in a bit. I got it working a different way, see below.

Comment: Could not get the controller thing to work for some reason :(. It's ok though, I have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you got time try this solution too. `this.get('priceSources')` it returns Promise so you need to access resultant in then method and wrap it in DS.PromiseObject so that you can access it like normal object in template.

```
cheapestSource: Ember.computed('priceSources.@each.price', function() {
        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
            promise: this.get('priceSources').then(sources => {
                let resultObj = {}
                    //sources is normal array you can apply your logic and set resultObj
                return resultObj;
            })
        });
    })
```

Comment: Is this supposed to go into a component (or controller) or model? Tried it in a model, got this: `Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).then is not a function`. I think this would be a nice solution, cos I would like to have cheapest as a computed property after having sorted the sources. E.g. inside the `sources =>` function, I could just return sources.firstObject, sources.get('firstObject'), sources[0] or whatever is the correct syntax there.

Comment: You can define it in model and by default `priceSources: DS.hasMany('price-source',{async:true})` . if async property true then it returns Promise so `then` is a thing and if its false it returns DS.ManyArray so `then` is not a thing so you will get that error. I havent worked out any example I just shim throguh this [ember igniter article for loading](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/) @VilleLehtinen